# mysqli_connect latency

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just recently had to reinstall my wamp package so I end up with a fresh apache 2.2.22, php 5.4.3 and mysql 5.5.24 .

One big change who occured was the page generation time. I dug a bit and found out that the call to mysqli_connect was taking up to 2 seconds.

So it still works, so my users have been well reconfigured and the whole system stands up - only this detail who make the whole unusable.

Does anyone knows where this latency could come from?

EDIT: it seems to be a dns problem as you proposed - Now, if I change to 127.0.0.1 I have an access-denied. I keep on digging

Comment: Is the database on the localhost? Are you calling it via `localhost` or   127.0.0.1 or some other name? You could have a DNS problem.

Comment: +1 for possible dns problem.  If reverse hostname lookups aren't being resolved quickly, then connections can be slow.  You can see this if you see 'unauthenticated user' in the processlist when you're waiting.  The fix is to add 'skip-name-resolve' in your my.cnf and restart mysql

Comment: The 'skip-name-resolve' allowed me to use our goo'old 127.0.0.1. Using the computer's name still takes ages but I could skip it by using either localhost either the IPv4 version.

There is still the question that this problem arrived with the installation of the fresh wamp (so using the computer name was not a problem - the dns system didn't change) but I'm happy and can already use that for now.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same exact, i was connecting to "localhost" and i had 1.5 sec for each "connect",
now i'm using 127.0.0.1 instead and it works great now !
FIY, tested with windows 2008 R2 x64 + plesk 11 php 5.3 (and php5.4 as well)

Comment: I had a 1 second latency. Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 worked for me! Using Wampserver 2.2 with PHP 5.4.3 on Windows 8 Pro x64

Comment: This solution helped also me.

Answer (score 0):

Well wildcards on C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts slowed every my request to 1s and more,

Handling multiple localhost names comma separated was horror (something with win7 DNS regexp)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost, domain.com
```

Spliting it i got again nice response without delay

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 domain.com
```